# How tdo I get the day of the week, of the first day of the month?

Tags: java

July 1, 2010 corresponds to a Thursday, how do I get the value of Thursday programmatically.

Comment: Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Calendar day= new GregorianCalendar(2010, Calendar.JULY, 1);
int dayOfWeek = day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); // 5=Thursday
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Date shiftDayOfWeekinMonth(Date input, int monthsToAdd) {

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(input);

int dayOfWeekInMonth = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);
int month = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);

// month increment
cal.add(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, monthsToAdd);
// sets the day of week in month
cal.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, dayOfWeekInMonth);

//overflow month control
int currentMonthIndex = (month + monthsToAdd) % 12;
if (currentMonthIndex != cal.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
    cal.add(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, -1);
}

return cal.getTime();
}
```

using this method to get any days of week in month for each month starting by an input date.

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

Using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.5 library rather than the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date and .Calendar classes.

Day of week numbers are define by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Monday is one, Sunday is seven.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime firstOfMonth = DateTime.now( zone ).withDayOfMonth( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
int dayOfWeekNumber = firstOfMonth.getDayOfWeek(); 
String dayName = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "EEEE" ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).print( firstOfMonth );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below method by Passing year and month as parameters

```
private String getFirstWeekOfTheMonth(int year, int month){
    String weeks[] = new String[]{"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thusday", "Friday", "Sunday"};
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.set(year, month, 1);
    return weeks[calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1];
}
```

**Example:-**

```
String currentWeek = getFirstWeekOfTheMonth(2010, Calendar.JULY);
```

here currentWeek is **Thursday**